# CSS animation keyframes with display none works to fade in, but not fade out

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an element which has display none on start. When i add a class to it i want it to fade in, using CSS.

I found [this tutorial](https://jdsteinbach.com/css/snippet-animate-display-transform/) to use keyframes which is working nice for fade in. But if i want to fade out the same way, the element gets hidden immediately with no animation.

Basically it looks like this:

```
.box {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: FadeOut 1s ease-in-out;

  &.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: FadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

Here is an "working" example:
http://codepen.io/MickL/pen/NAopXN

Comment: As you see in the example, i animate it for fade in.

Comment: When you remove `display: none` in you `.box` selector, the animation becomes smooth, but the box won't collapse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trying to animate the `display:none` is the root of your problem. The confusion for why the fade-in works and the fade-out doesn't comes from the combination of using both `display` and `opacity`.

The `display` property is only being dictated by whether `.active` is applied; the animations aren't actually changing it, whereas the `opacity` is animated as expected. On the fade-in, this means that you immediately show your element, which then transitions from transparent to opaque. On the fade-out, this means that you immediately hide your element, which then transitions from opaque to transparent while hidden.

There are a couple different ways you could solve this, but it sort of depends on the context. For example, you could leave it as a `block` element and use the `height` property to make it collapse:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
@import "bourbon";
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: FadeOut 1s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  height: initial;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: FadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: initial;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: initial;
  }
}
@keyframes FadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: initial;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: initial;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Toggle display</button>
  <p class="box good">I move nicely!</p>
  <p>Extra paragraph to show collapse</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Only problem is that i see the fadeout-animation when the page loads :(

Comment: You could potentially fix that by putting the `FadeOut` animation on a separate class (e.g. `inactive`). Instead of toggling `active`, you would add and remove the two classes as needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that `height: 0` keeps the element as part of the document tree, potentially tripping up e.g. keyboard users (tabbing onto items in the zero-height div) and assistive technologies like screen readers. I am not aware of a nice, neat, clean solution to this, but some JavaScript can help: https://codepen.io/alanhogan/pen/ExpyXQy

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate or transition the display property.

*Note: That's not to say you can't use it in keyframe animation but that's not the same as **actually** animating it.*

The reason why your Codepen demo doesn't work as intended is because the `.active` class is being removed **instantly** so the animation out has no time to fire and the default `display:none` is now applied immediately.

Since you are using Jquery anyway, there is a built in function `fadeToggle` which will do what you want.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('.box').fadeToggle(500);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Toggle display</button>
  <p class="box good">I move nicely!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you really didn't...it might look like it but it's not animatable. You can use it in a keyframe but it **instantly** switches from `none` to `block`

Comment: In the example i didnt used prefixes. This may not work in some browsers so you may not see it. I tested in chrome which doesn't need a prefix. if you add -moz- to animation and keyframes it will work ...

Comment: You don't understand, it's not animatable....but it can be used in an animation...that's not the same thing. The root cause of your problem is that the second fade animation never fires because the class is removed instantly...and the display reverts back to none **instantly**...because it can't be animated/transitioned.

Comment: The `display` property is not animatable _at all_ according to the Formal Definition section on MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_definition Note this is unlike e.g. `visibility` which  is treated as animating between 0 and 1 and which results in visibility for values greater than 0. So, `display` cannot be used in an `@animation`.

Comment: I am aware read my above comment