# Recursive function to change opacity (efect fadein with pure js)

Tags: javascript, fadein, pure-js

Why this code is not changing opacity value in progress?

```js
function fadeIn(arg_idElemHtml,arg_opacityValue) {
    if(arg_opacityValue < 1){
      var objHtml = document.getElementById(arg_idElemHtml);
      objHtml.style.display = 'block';
      objHtml.style.opacity = arg_opacityValue + 0.1;
      arg_opacityValue = parseFloat(arg_opacityValue) + 0.1;
      setTimeout(fadeIn(arg_idElemHtml,arg_opacityValue), 400);
    }
}
```

```css
#msg {background-color:red;display:none;opacity:0.0}
```

```html
<button id="bt" onclick="fadeIn('msg',0);">GO</button>
<div id="msg">content message</div>
```

Comment: The answer below is correct, you are calling your function instead of passing a callback, but it looks like a simple CSS animation is all that is needed? something like [Display none in CSS fade out does not work or hide the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866859/display-none-in-css-fade-out-does-not-work-or-hide-the-div) or [CSS animation keyframes with display none works to fade in, but not fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934595/css-animation-keyframes-with-display-none-works-to-fade-in-but-not-fade-out)

Comment: but with no JS how can i detect click event with only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate my comment regarding using CSS to handle the fade in on click.

I've used [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline handler assignment which is generally recommended. I have also used classes to define the re-usable fade related CSS. This avoids duplication if you are going to reuse the functionality as well as resolving [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issues that arise in mixing `id` and `class` based style assignments.

```js
const bt = document.getElementById('bt');

bt.addEventListener('click', () => fadeIn('msg'));

function fadeIn(id) {
  const objHTML = document.getElementById(id);
  objHTML.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
#msg {
  background-color: red;
}

.fade-in {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeInAnimation 2s;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="bt">Go</button>
<div id="msg" class="fade-in hidden">content message</div>
```

For extended discussion see:

[Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property).

Take the time to read through all the answers, the top voted or accepted answer may not be the most relevant to your situation.

##### Edit - Fade Out

It is a little more involved to add a fade out effect, since you don't want to set `display: none;` until the animation is complete. Here is an example using the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event) event to cleanup/complete the transition.

Whether showing or hiding the element we first add a listener on the `animationend` event that will cleanup the classes added to handle the animation. When adding the listener it is important to pass an options object with `{once: true}` which will remove the listener after the first time it runs. This is to ensure we don't create multiple listeners on the same element.

Having added the cleanup listener we proceed to add the relevant fade class — If the element is hidden we add the `fade-in` class and remove the `hidden` class, otherwise we add the `fade-out` class to begin the animation. You'll note that we are reusing the same keyframes CSS by using the [animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) property to reverse it in the `fade-out` class.

```js
const bt = document.getElementById("bt");

bt.addEventListener("click", () => fade("msg"));

function fade(id) {
  const objHTML = document.getElementById(id);

  if (objHTML.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    const fadeInCleanup = () => {
      objHTML.classList.remove("fade-in");
    };

    objHTML.addEventListener("animationend", fadeInCleanup, { once: true });

    objHTML.classList.add("fade-in");
    objHTML.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    const fadeOutCleanup = () => {
      objHTML.classList.remove("fade-out");
      objHTML.classList.add("hidden");
    };

    objHTML.addEventListener("animationend", fadeOutCleanup, { once: true });

    objHTML.classList.add("fade-out");
  }
}
```

```css
#msg {
  background-color: red;
}

#next-msg {
  background-color: pink;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.fade-in {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.fade-out {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="bt">Go</button>
<div id="msg" class="block hidden">fading message</div>
<div id="next-msg">persistent message</div>
```

Comment: ok, i am gonna try it on different browsers.  Thank you very much!!!   Is there anyway to do it without JS @pilchard ?

Comment: Not on click. If you wanted it on hover you could.

Comment: ok perfect.   Another last question:  In that example that you has written... would it be possible to add fadeOut effect to same div 'msg' ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I just added a fade-out example.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you set the callback in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) wrong.

```js
function fadeIn(arg_idElemHtml,arg_opacityValue) {
    if(arg_opacityValue < 1){
      var objHtml = document.getElementById(arg_idElemHtml);
      objHtml.style.display = 'block';
      objHtml.style.opacity = arg_opacityValue + 0.1;
      
      arg_opacityValue = parseFloat(arg_opacityValue) + 0.1;
      
      // Like this
      setTimeout(() => fadeIn(arg_idElemHtml,arg_opacityValue),400);
      
      // Or
      // setTimeout(fadeIn.bind(this, arg_idElemHtml,arg_opacityValue),400);
    }
}
```

```css
#msg {background-color:red;display:none;opacity:0.0}
```

```html
<button id="bt" onclick="fadeIn('msg',0);">GO</button>
<div id="msg">content message</div>
```